# What to use to get uncaught exception / crash reports

Tags: android, exception, crash-reports

I am debugging an Android application.

The problem is that there are some elusive Activity crashes.

They are not Application crashes, but rather Activity crashes, since the application does not close, only the current activity does.

The point is that Google Play does not send me the information about these kinds of exceptions and Activity crashes.

Please any suggestion?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You really should try [Crashlytics](https://crashlytics.com/). [Cittercism](http://www.crittercism.com/) is quite good too.

Answer (score 1):

You can try using http://try.crashlytics.com/ which does a good job of providing crash reports .

Alternatively, you can debug & use try-catch around the areas of code that are high risk for crashing and figure out where the problem is from that.

Answer (score 1):

You can use any crash analytic library . There many library is available in the market. some library is paid. you can use this library.

http://try.crashlytics.com/

Answer (score 1):

I've been using [HockeyApp](http://hockeyapp.net/features/) for a while and it is really nice